# How to add sku on minicart?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I tried,

Test\Cart\view\frontend\web\template\default.

```
<tr class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
<div class="product">
    <div class="product-item-details">
        <td class="prod-name">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->                 
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_sku"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_sku --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td class="prod-price">
            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                 <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div data-bind="html: 'SKU#: ' + item.product_sku"></div>
               </div>
           </td>
           <td class="prod-qty">
                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <!-- label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label> -->
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                           maxlength="12"/>

                </div>
        </td>
        <td class="prod-qty prod-edit">
            <div class="product actions">
              <div class="secondary">
                  <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                     class="action delete">
                      <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </td>
    </div>
</div>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the code:

```
        <span class="product-item-name">
         <!-- ko text: product_sku --><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
```

to **`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html`**
 after   `</strong>`

---

First copy **`default.html`**

> **`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\`**

to theme folder:

> **`app\design\frontend\{YourvendorName}\{YourTheme}\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\item\`**

```
    <div class="product-item-details">
        <strong class="product-item-name">
            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </strong>
        <!-- add sku -->
        <span class="product-item-name">
         <!-- ko text: product_sku --><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- ko if: options.length -->
        <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
            <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                <dl class="product options list">
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                    <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                    <dd class="values">
                        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-pricing">
            <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

            <div class="details-map">
                <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="details-qty qty">
                <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                       for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                <input data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       'data-item-qty': qty,
                       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                       }, value: qty"
                       type="number"
                       size="4"
                       class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                       maxlength="12"/>
                <button data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       title: $t('Update')
                       }"
                        class="update-cart-item"
                        style="display: none">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product actions">
            <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
            <div class="primary">
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="secondary">
                <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                   class="action delete">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Most important:

- FLush Magento
- delete all files  from `var/cache ,var/view_preprocessed`
- deploy static content by `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**Please fellow the steps for reflect the changes.**

Comment: Thanko you so much